Ubuntu as a multi-interface router for OpenVPN
I would like to setup an Ubuntu system to act as a VPN router for different network segments, either physical ethernets or VLANs. The following figure depicts the desired outcome.
Ubuntu OpenVPN router diagram:

The two OpenVPN configurations both work independently, but send traffic from Ubuntu to the respective VPN server. I only want the eth1 and eth2 traffic forwarded to the VPN servers and any received traffic sent back on the ethX interface. The DHCP server should provide IP addresses to devices on the eth1 and eth2 networks.
I'm sure this is related to IP forwarding in Ubuntu, but that's not something I am familiar with.
